# Just vs. lately in the present perfect

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Can we use *lately* instead of *just* in the following sentence:

> I’ve just gotten back from London. It was a business trip.

Does it have any meaning?

Answer (score 2):

You can, and it would mean *recently*, but it would be rather unusual.